# How to get the text of the option inside the select from the appended html using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

[image]I am using form and appending select with option that are values and text is from the php for multiple. My problem is I cannot get the text of the selected option. I will get first the text from the appended html  Can someone help me?  Here is my code:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         fetch_ssi_request();
         var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
         var x = 1;

         $("#add_row").click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var form = '<div class="row row-'+x+'" style="margin-bottom:10px">'+'<div class="col-md-5">'+'<select class="form-control" name="program[]" id="select_program-'+x+'" required>'
                      +'<option value="">-- Please select a program -- </option>';
                      <?php foreach($programs as $key){ ?>
                      var val = "<?php echo $key->program ?>";
                      var name = "<?php echo $key->title ?>";
                      form+='<option value="'+val+'">'+name+'</option>';
                      <?php } ?>
                      form+='</select></div>';
                      form+='<div class="col-md-5">'+'<select class="form-control" name="accreditation[]" id="select_level-'+x+'" required>'
                      +'<option value="">-- Please select an accreditation level -- </option>';
                      <?php foreach($accreditation as $key){ ?>
                      var lvl_val = "<?php echo $key->accred_id ?>";
                      var lvl_name = "<?php echo $key->accred_title ?>";
                      form+='<option value="'+lvl_val+'">'+lvl_name+'</option>';
                      <?php } ?>
                      form+='</select></div><div class="col-md-2">';
                          $('.form_ssi').append(form+'<button class="btn btn-danger" div-id="'+x+'" id="delete_row"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></button></div></div>');
                           x++;
           console.log(x);


           $(document).on("change", "#select_program-"+x-1, function () {
            //Here is the problem empty is the output of the console log                                
             console.log($("#select_program-"+x-1).find(":selected").text());
             $("#select_level-"+(x-1)+" option[value='2']").remove();

           });                                               
});
```

Here is the HTML code
HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px">

                    <div class="col-md-5">
                            <select class="form-control" name="program[]" id="select_program-0" required>
                                <option value="">-- Please select a SSI/Guideline -- </option>
                                <?php foreach($programs as $key){ ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $key->program?>"><?php echo $key->title?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <select class="form-control" name="accreditation[]"id="select_level-0" required>
                            <option value="">-- Please select an accreditation level/guideline -- </option>
                            <?php foreach($accreditation as $key){ ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $key->accred_id?>"><?php echo $key->accred_title?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div><!--.col-md-5-->
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_row"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></button>
                     </div>
                </div><!--.row--> 
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="add_row"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add More</button></br>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Are your `option` tags rendering as expected from the `php` script you are using? If so then please include an example of the rendered output, this will make your source code much easier to work with to provide you a solution and find the reason your current attempt isn't functioning as intended.

Comment: I would also recommend you swap from using `id`'s like `#select_program-(?)` to a `class` if you want to run one function for a group of elements. It's one of many reasons `class` exists and makes things much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first, this is why you should not mix PHP and Javascript and HTML :) (bad for debugging and readability). Separate your php code to a view file and get that through ajax.

Few things I figured out (please keep in mind that the code you provided is impossible to try it out (as you have php inside it):

1. I didn't see the closing parenthesis for you click event. If you have, make sure it closes before your `change` event.
2. Make use of 'this' context and this is why you have 'this' in javascript. eg:

   ```
    $(document).on("change", "#select_program-"+x-1, function () {
       //Here is the problem empty is the output of the console log                                
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
   ```

This should work as long as the selector `"#select_program-"+x-1` is good. Like I said too hard to debug and try it out myself.

Also, use `class` so you don't have to care about making `id` unique.

```
 <select class="form-control" name="program[]" class="select_program" required>

 $(document).on("change", ".select_program", function () {
        //Here is the problem empty is the output of the console log                                
         console.log($(this).val());
 });
```

**Update after comment,**

Now you have to remove an option (assuming it depends on the option selected). Ok so let's start where your accreditation element is. It will always be next to the select element that you are currently in (unless you change the html). So make use of next:

```
 $(document).on("change", ".select_program", function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
    //add your condition here
    //fine the accreditation select.
    $(this).closest('div')
           .next()
           .find('select.select_level')
           .remove('whatever you like')
    // $(this) is the current select box,
    // .closest(div) finds the closest parent div which is <div class="col-md-5">
    // next() goes to siblings of that div which is <div class="col-md-5">
    // find(.select_level) finds the select box inside it with class select_level. Make sure to change the id to class
    // do what ever you need to do. I used `remove()` you can use anything you want here.

 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. this is now working but how do I achieve like this. If I click this option I want to remove an option on the accreditation select box?

Comment: @TepTep UPDATED  :).. happy coding